# how can i fetch a given number of record like 200 for each user_id where column 'last name'='some value'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a table with more than 50,000 records i want to select 200 records for each user_id in the table where last_name='somevalue' and display the results am new in laravel please help

```
  $users = DB::table('leads')
           ->having('last_name', '=', 'Taladpd43.')
            ->limit(200)
            ->groupBy('user_id')
             ->get();
          return response()->json($users);
```

i expected 200 records for each user but actually got the first 2 rows

Comment: So the query in this question should return only a maximum of 200 records?

Comment: Are you using eloquent models or prefer to use the `DB` facade.

Comment: from your record, do you think you have more than 200 records of last_name matching Taladpd43? you could match that dynamically you know.